# How do I preserve a Windows 10 Pro license while experimenting with Hyper-V?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v, license, hypervisor

I have a copy of Windows Server 2016 and am trying to learn all I can about Virtual Machines.  I expect that the early machines I build will improve as I build more.  I'd like to build some Windows 10 VMs, and I suspect that I'd like to clear them from time to time and start over.  My understanding is that Windows 10 license activates against certain hardware.

Is there a way to have a very basic image of the VM preserved with the purchased license, and when you want to deactivate a machine, you can start from scratch with the license preserved on a new machine?

Comment: You dont have to activate Windows.  If its just short term experiments, you can skip the license key.

Comment: Take a look at checkpoints.  You can create your base image, activate it, and create a checkpoint.  Make your changes, experiment, etc, then delete the checkpoint and you're back to your original clean image.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to build some Windows 10 VMs, and I suspect that I'd like to clear them from time to time and start over. My understanding is that Windows 10 license activates against certain hardware.

The activation status of Windows on a VM will not be impacted by the number of CPU cores or the amount of memory you assigned to the VM.

> Is there a way to have a very basic image of the VM preserved with the purchased license?

There is nothing you have to do special to accomplish your goal.

> when you want to deactivate a machine, you can start from scratch with the license preserved on a new machine?

If the license is linked to a Microsoft Account, if the machine has the same name, you don't have to do anything.  If you change the name of the machine, simply remove the old machine from your account, and activate the license on the new machine.